# Magento 2 Adding an address to an account in PHP

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, magento2.2.3

I  am working on a module that adds an account in the checkout in Magento 2.3

I am able to create an account now but i'm struggling with adding an address to that account. I already tried multiple different ways by using the customer address factory.

> /Model/Checkout/ShippingInformationManagementPlugin.php

```
<?php
 namespace BB\Checkout\Model\Checkout;

 class ShippingInformationManagementPlugin
 {
protected $quoteRepository;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory
 */
protected $subscriberFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface
 */
protected $accountManagement;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Helper\Address
 */
protected $addressHelper;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory
 */
protected $formFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterfaceFactory
 */
protected $regionDataFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory
 */
protected $addressDataFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Registration
 */
protected $registration;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory
 */
protected $customerDataFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Url
 */
protected $customerUrl;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
 */
protected $escaper;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerExtractor
 */
protected $customerExtractor;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
 */
protected $urlModel;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper
 */
protected $dataObjectHelper;

/**
 * @var Session
 */
protected $session;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $storeManager;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory
 */
protected $customerFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory
 */
protected $addressFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository,
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionAttributesFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,

    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,

    \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $addressFactory
)
{
    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    $this->subscriberFactory = $subscriberFactory;
    $this->extensionAttributesFactory = $extensionAttributesFactory;
    $this->observer = $observer;

    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    $this->addressFactory = $addressFactory;
}

/**
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject
 * @param $cartId
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
 */
public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
    $cartId,
    \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
)
{
    $extAttributes = $addressInformation->getExtensionAttributes();
    $email = $extAttributes->getEmail();

    // Create account for user
     if ($extAttributes->getPassword() !== '') {

        // Get Website ID
        $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();

        // Instantiate object (this is the most important part)
        $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $address = $addressInformation->getShippingAddress();

        // Preparing data for new customer
        $customer->setEmail($extAttributes->getEmail());
        $customer->setPassword($extAttributes->getPassword());
        $customer->setFirstname($address->getFirstname());
        $customer->setLastname($address->getLastname());

//            //Address data (not working)
//            $customer->setStreet($address->getStreet());
//            $customer->setPostcode($address->getPostcode());
//            $customer->setCity($address->getCity());
//            $customer->setCountry($address->getCountry());
//            $customer->setTelephone($address->getTelephone());

        // Save data
        try {
            $customer->save();

            echo 'Create customer successfully, customer ID: ' . $customer->getId();
            $addAddress = $this->addressFactory->create();

            $addAddress->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
            $addAddress->setCountryId('NL');
            $addAddress->setPostcode('6942AE');
            $addAddress->setCity('Arnhem');
            $addAddress->setTelephone('0123456789');
            $addAddress->setStreet('Street 1');
            $addAddress->setIsDefaultBilling('1');
            $addAddress->setIsDefaultShipping('1');
            $addAddress->setSaveInAddressBook('1');

            $addAddress->save();

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // E-mail address is already added, this will occur if the customer goes back and forward in steps, the account is already created by then.
        }
    }
}
}
```

It saves the account but doesn't add the address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what I was missing but I changed around some variable names and somehow it works now.

*ShippingInformationManagementPlugin.php*

```
<?php

 namespace BB\Checkout\Model\Checkout;

 class ShippingInformationManagementPlugin
{
protected $quoteRepository;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory
 */
protected $subscriberFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface
 */
protected $accountManagement;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Helper\Address
 */
protected $addressHelper;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory
 */
protected $formFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterfaceFactory
 */
protected $regionDataFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory
 */
protected $addressDataFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Registration
 */
protected $registration;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory
 */
protected $customerDataFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Url
 */
protected $customerUrl;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
 */
protected $escaper;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerExtractor
 */
protected $customerExtractor;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
 */
protected $urlModel;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper
 */
protected $dataObjectHelper;

/**
 * @var Session
 */
protected $session;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $storeManager;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory
 */
protected $customerFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory
 */
protected $addressFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository,
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionAttributesFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,

    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,

    \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $addressFactory
)
{
    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    $this->subscriberFactory = $subscriberFactory;
    $this->extensionAttributesFactory = $extensionAttributesFactory;
    $this->observer = $observer;

    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    $this->addressFactory = $addressFactory;
}

/**
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject
 * @param $cartId
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
 */
public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
    $cartId,
    \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
)
{
    $extAttributes = $addressInformation->getExtensionAttributes();
    $email = $extAttributes->getEmail();
    $subscribe = $extAttributes->getSubscribe();

    // Subscribe user to newsletter
    if ($subscribe === true) {
        $subscriber = $this->subscriberFactory->create()->loadByEmail($email);
        if ($subscriber->getId() && $subscriber->getSubscriberStatus() == \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED) {
        } else {
            $status = $this->subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($email);
        }
    }

    // Create account for user
     if ($extAttributes->getPassword() !== '') {

        // Create account
        $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
        $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $address = $addressInformation->getShippingAddress();

        // Preparing data for new customer
        $customer->setEmail($extAttributes->getEmail());
        $customer->setPassword($extAttributes->getPassword());
        $customer->setFirstname($address->getFirstname());
        $customer->setLastname($address->getLastname());

        try {
            $customer->save();

            // Create address
            $customerAddress = $this->addressFactory->create();

            $customerAddress->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
            $customerAddress->setFirstname($address->getFirstname());
            $customerAddress->setLastname($address->getFirstname());
            $customerAddress->setCountryId($address->getCountryId());
            $customerAddress->setPostcode($address->getPostcode());
            $customerAddress->setCity($address->getCity());
            $customerAddress->setTelephone($address->getTelephone());
            $customerAddress->setStreet($address->getStreet());
            $customerAddress->setCompany($address->getCompany());
            $customerAddress->setVatId($address->getVatId());
            $customerAddress->setIsDefaultBilling('1');
            $customerAddress->setIsDefaultShipping('1');
            $customerAddress->setSaveInAddressBook('1');

            $customerAddress->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // E-mail address is already added, this will occur if the customer goes back and forward in steps, the account is already created by then.
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$addresss = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory');

$address = $addresss->create();

$address->setCustomerId($customer->getId())

->setFirstname(FirstName)

->setLastname(LastName)

->setCountryId(US)

->setPostcode(20000)

->setCity(city)

->setTelephone(123456)

->setFax(123456789)

->setCompany(Company)

->setStreet(Street)

->setIsDefaultBilling('1')

->setIsDefaultShipping('1')

->setSaveInAddressBook('1')

$address->save();
```

Comment: I already tried that but it didn't work sadly.

Comment: @Sanne have got any error in var/log ?